# Question about C++ syntax in V8's TYPE_CHECK macro

Tags: c++, v8

Once reading v8.h in V8 engine code, I could find the following macro.

```
#define TYPE_CHECK(T, S)                                       \
  while (false) {                                              \
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
  }
```

I know that this is to check the type S is compatible with the type T. In the statement, how can the execution flow enter the while loop? **while(false)** means that condition is always false. Thus,  the statement in while loop will never be executed.

As a result, the macro is not always usable, is it?

Comment: Perhaps this is meant to fail at compile time... Or they could've just been evil and done something like `#define false true`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As a result, the macro is not always usable, is it?

The macro is always usable. The intent is to produce a compile-time error or warning (namely that one type is not compatible with another).

The purpose of wrapping it in `while (false)` is to prevent the code ever executing at runtime - and with modern compilers the code probably never makes it in to the final binary (optimised out).

If you want to know more about this technique, read up on [static assertions](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/gcc/static_assert.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand what the macro means. That is, if type S is not compatible with type T, compiler makes an error or a warning in compile time.